# Android - "Unable to resolve host" - How to configure S3_UploaderActvity from Amazon AWS SDK samples?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I've followed Amazon's [Getting Started](http://aws.amazon.com/developers/getting-started/android/) guide, and (after Exporting the Amazon library, [increasing the heap size available to Eclipse](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_increase_the_heap_size_available_to_Eclipse?) and adding the necessary permissions to the application manifest), I now have the sample S3_UploaderActivity Android app running.

However, when I try to upload an image I get this error message on my device's screen:

> Unable to execute HTTP request: Unable to resolve host
>   "my-unique-namexxxxxxxxxxxxxxxpicture-bucket.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com": No address associated with hostname

Although this wasn't mentioned in the Getting Started guide, I presumably need to change the "my-unique-name" and "picture-bucket" strings (the latter which is stored in a constant called PICTURE_BUCKET).

But what do I change these values to??

Comment: Also, I have created my bucket at https://console.aws.amazon.com/s3/home using 'Oregon' as the Region as this region seems to correspond to the "s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com" part of the URL which is hardcoded into the sample app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you add the internet permission to your manifest file ?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: Thanks, yes, I have added the two necessary permissions...
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
...I'm pretty sure the problem is to do with the string(s) I mentioned.

Comment: Yes, obviously "my-unique-namexxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" does not exist and needs to be replaced with your subdomain name. So you answered your own question.

Comment: I didn't know I even have a subdomain name. Where do I find this?

Comment: It looks like Amazon automatically creates a subdomain name for your picture bucket. That's why the app can't find the domain name if you don't specify a valid picture bucket.

Comment: OK, but where do I find it? I have gone to https://console.aws.amazon.com/s3/home?region=us-west-2 and looked through my bucket's permissons, but there is no hint of a subdomain anywhere. I have tried using my bucket name instead of "my-unique-name" but that didn't work either.

Comment: Problem sorted. Ahem, the wi-fi on my phone wasn't turned on / no network connection. Not sure whether to laugh or cry...

Comment: It seems the "my-unique-name" string can be anything.

Comment: And you don't need to create the bucket online beforehand. In fact, it will not work if you do that as there is a restriction with the  S3_UploaderActivity sample app in that it must create the bucket itself.